# Running specific tests with TestNG programmatically

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

While tests are being executed, I populate a List of failedTests.
I want to rerun these tests programmatically when the suite completes.
Following the TestNG documentation, I implemented the following logic:

```
public void retrySuiteVirtXml(){
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.addListener(tla);

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("Retry Suite");

    for (ITestResult testResult : failedTests){
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest();
        xmlTest.setSuite(suite);

        String newTestName = testResult.getName();
        xmlTest.setName(newTestName);

        List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        xmlClasses.add(new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass().getName()));
        xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClasses);

        xmlTest.getClasses().addAll(xmlClasses);
        suite.addTest(xmlTest);
    }

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
    suites.add(suite);
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    //tng.run();
    tng.runSuitesLocally();

}
```

However, this block runs every test that appears in the class of a failed test.
I cannot figure out how to make the TestNG only run the failed tests (List failedTests).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing tests with methods.  You should be building your included methods based on the failed tests.  You can try creating a map of class to their methods first and then add the classes to a single Test.  Core algo below :

```
 Map<String, List<XmlInclude>> classToMethodsMap = new HashMap<String, List<XmlInclude>>();
        for (ITestResult testResult : failedTests){

            //Create map of failed classes to methods
            if(classToMethodsMap.get(testResult.getTestClass().getName()) == null){
                List<XmlInclude> methods = new ArrayList<XmlInclude>();
                methods.add(new XmlInclude(testResult.getMethod().getMethodName()));
                classToMethodsMap.put(testResult.getTestClass().getName(),methods);
            }else{
                classToMethodsMap.get(testResult.getTestClass().getName()).add(new XmlInclude(testResult.getTestClass().getName()));
            }
        }

        List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        for(String className : classToMethodsMap.keySet()){
            XmlClass  xmlClassToAdd =new XmlClass(className);
            xmlClassToAdd.setIncludedMethods(classToMethodsMap.get(className));
            xmlClasses.add(xmlClassToAdd);

        }
        xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClasses);
        suite.addTest(xmlTest);
```

Comment: small correction in the "else" block: .add(new XmlInclude(testResult.getMethod().getMethodName()))

Comment: In my test framework, I placed some logic in the TestNG listeners (onTestFailure, onTestSkipped). I save the results into a DB. The solution works, the tests are run, but the listener is not called. I.e. the code that is located in the "onTestFailuer" block is called only once, but when the test is run again the method "onTestFailure" is not called. Do you know what is missed? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, I was missing the tng.setListenerClasses(listeners);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setExcludedMethods` on `XmlClass` to filter methods.

And without specific need, only one `XmlTest` should be enough.